# Is there some result that says a theory cannot prove the consistency of any of its extensions?

Tags: logic, ordinals, proof-theory, incompleteness

Is there some result that says a (sufficiently strong) theory cannot prove the consistency of any of its extensions?

Or something along these lines??

More generally, is there a result that says a (sufficiently strong) theory cannot prove the consistency of *any* stronger theory, for some notion of strength (proof-ordinals?), maybe with some conditions?

Comment: If $T\cup S$ is consistent, then $T$ is consistent. I'm not sure where the difficulty here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this follows directly from the 2nd incompleteness theorem.

By definition, a theory is inconsistent iff it contains both the statement $S$ and $\neg S$ for some statement $S$.

An extension of a theory contains all of the statements of that theory.  Therefor if the extension is consistent, then the original theory is as well, since any such statements $S, \neg S$ in the original theory are also in the extension.